# Wordpress Front-End Theme Editor

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to change my option panel to the front-end. 
So user can see whats happening with the site.
Changes must be real-time.

Searched allover but cant find a way to solve this.

Comment: This question really cannot be answered specifically as it is currently written. Can you provide additional information regarding *what you have*, and *how you want to change it*? As it is currently, the question is both too vague and too broadly scoped to be a good fit for WPSE.

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress 3.4 you have something called Theme Customizer that provide a optionpanel within **wp-admin** that enables you to see the changes in real-time. Maybe thats an option to go?

Look at this video to see how it works: http://www.youtube.com/embed/amUjCfpIsJ4

Then you have themes like [Headway](http://headwaythemes.com/) that you can change the theme appearance on the front-end and add your own settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid nothing like that exists to my knowledge either.  If you're looking to edit CSS code live, then I would suggest using the [Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox.  You're able to actually go in and edit the CSS code live on the screen.  However, when you save you'll lose your changes.  But the good thing is that once you find the CSS code that works, you can copy that right to your source and "Viola!" you have the correct code implemented.  It's at least a little bit faster than uploading and refreshing your screen every time.